# SQL Server CE could not load file or assembly if the project is on a network

Tags: c#, networking, dll, sql-server-ce, impersonation

My application uses a `.sdf` database file and classes from the `System.Data.SqlServerCE` namespace to access it.

But it can't find it if I put my application on a network for sharing it with others.

I know that SQL Server Compact is a single-user database, but why can't it find the databsae when run on the network? Also I get error messages like:

> Attempting to download of new URL:
>
> any/path/lib/System.Data.SQLServerCE.exe
>   any/path/lib/System.Data.SQLServerCE.dll

Additionally I only have that problem if I impersonate another user in my program...

Comment: Running SQL CE on a network is not supported, you should use SQL Server Express instead - Did you install the SQL Server Compact runtime on the PC?

Comment: Yes i installed SQL Server Compact runtime. I need a Offline Database for a Offline working Program. Is SQL Server Express support this offline Database feature?

Comment: Clarify Offline? SQL Express is a Windows Service, and must be installed somewhere...

Comment: I wanna load a compressed Database File like .sdf without going online